# Is it possible to use .htaccess to instruct browsers to cache google analytics?

Tags: .htaccess, google, cache-control

When I run [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) I get the following optimization suggestion.

[image: Leverage browser caching]

When I click the [Leverage browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) link it sends me to a page that recommends I use [Cache-Control](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control) or [ETags](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#validating-cached-responses-with-etags).

Setting up `Cache-Control` with `.htaccess` should be simple enough so I included the following lines inside of my existing `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

<filesMatch "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch> 

<filesMatch "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-00000000-0">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=900, public"
</filesMatch> 

</IfModule>
```

I uploaded the `.htaccess` file, tested it and got the same error.  Even though Google recommends using `Cache-Control` that doesn't solve the problem.

When that didn't work I tried `ExpiresByType` but it didn't solve them problem either.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive On

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 hours"
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to use an `.htaccess` file to instruct browsers to cache these files or is that not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in `.htaccess` can affect a domain outside of your control.

You have a couple options.

- Self-host the gtag.js file, which is [possible but not recommended](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en).
- Proxy the gtag.js file, adding your own headers to it. This addresses the main concern (updates) from the above doc.
- Ignore it. It's essentially a false-positive; Google has presumably *intentionally* set a low cache time for these assets for a reason.